# Javascript countdown is getting faster after each run

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, time, timer

```
var i = 3400;

function progress() {
    i = 34000;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        i = i - 100;
        document.getElementById("progress").firstChild.data = i;
    }, 100);
}
```

This code is getting faster and faster. The function progress is called every 3 seconds, but I can't change the it's called because it's event based. After around 10 calls i is getting negative!

Comment: The problem here is that you call progress multiple times which in turn initiates multiple timers with the call to setInterval. That way you are generating an interval every 3 seconds. So after 9 seconds you have 3 intervals running, after 15 seconds you have 5 and so on. Maybe post some more details as to what exactly you are trying to achive.

Comment: I have a some sliding Images, and the methode is called when the animation is finished. I want to have the time until the next Images will slide.

Comment: For one thing, you don't check if your countdown ever reaches zero, maybe you should do that and stop the interval then. Second, why not call the function to slide at the end of your countdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since progress is called every 3 seconds, you need to avoid that it creates new intervals repeatedly. Using `clearTimeout` resets the timer anytime you call progress. However, without knowing what exactly you want to achive it's difficult to provide an accurate answer.

```
var timeout;

function counter(count) {

    document.getElementById("progress").firstChild.data = count;

    if (count >= 0) {
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            counter(count-100);
        }, 100);
    }
}

function progress() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    counter(3400);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Umm....

Do not use `setInterval`

You probably want to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var i = 3400;

function progress() {
     i = i - 100;
     document.getElementById("progress").firstChild.data = i;
     window.setTimeout('progress();', 100);
}
```

Comment: The interval is too short that the next progress executes before the first one is finished. Try increasing the progress time to 1000